# Divergent series : its subsequence sum to arbitrary number

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of positive real number. Assume that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \infty, \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0.$$ Then for any positive real number $a$, there exists a subsequence $(a_{n_k})$ such that $$\sum_{k =1}^\infty a_{n_k} = a.$$

The statement is, more or less, analogous to Riemann rearrangement theorem for conditionally convergent series (http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/RiemannRearrangementTheorem.shtml). I can imagine why the theorem is possible. It is like $a_n$ each is tiny, but when it sum together it can be gigantic. So for any positive number $a$, it is like I need to have a finite sum of $a_n$ up to where it is near $a$. Then use the tail term of $a_n$ that really small, say might be smaller than $1/2^n$ so it infinite sum is tiny, to fill up the gap between to finite sum of $a_n$ and $a$.

However, I cannot write the proof. It is hard to set up the finite sum until it almost reach $a$. I try to mimic the proof in Riemann theorem, but it is considerably different form this statement.

Help please.

Comment: If $a< a_1 $ we just don't use $a_1$.

Comment: @user117375 "The current answers do not contain enough detail." Sorry but if you are referring to PenasRaul's answer, this is simply not true.

Answer (score 3):

Construct the sequence by hand (that's actually the proof that I know from Riemann's theorem):

Given $n_1, \cdots , n_k $, we pick $n_{k+1} $ as the smallest index $i > n_k$ such that $a_i < a - \sum\limits_{j=1}^k a_{n_j}$.

This process converges because the tails always sum $\infty $.

Comment: So it sounds like induction argument. Since $a_n \rightarrow 0$, there exists $a_i < a$. Set $a_{n_1} = a_{i}$ where $i$ is smallest possible (exist by well-ordering principle). Now, choose smallest $j>n_j$ such that $a_j < a - a_{n_1}$. Assume we choose $n_{k_1}, ...., n_{k_j}$, choose smallest $j+1 > n_{k_j}$ with $a_{j+1} < a - \sum_{j=1}^k a_{n_j}$. Then the induction give a subsequence. However, how can you show that $(a_{n_k})$ does converges to $a$ ? I think it does not that obvious that it does converge to $a$.

Comment: Suppose that it does not converge to $a$ but to $a-z $.
The subsequence $n_k$ is strictly increasing by definition.
Define $m_k$ as the dual sequence, the increasing sequence that is disjoint from $n_k$ and covers all the remaining integers. Think of this as the set (rather than a sequence) of numbers that do not occur on $n_k$.

Note that $a_{m_k}$ should never be bigger than $z $, by construction!

$\sum_k a_k - \sum_k a_{n_k} $ is divergent, there are infinitely many numbers that do not occur in $n_k$, hence $m_k$ is actually infinite.
Then $a_{m_k} \to 0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: I try to think about it for hours. I don't see why $a_{m_k}$ should never bigger than $z$. Another thing is where is the contradiction, $a_{m_k}$ is basically one subsequence of $a_n$ which converges to zero. Any of its subsequence should also converges to zero. I don't see a contradiction.

Comment: This is not a complete proof. You never use the fact that the sequence converges to zero, and clearly the statement is false without it.

Comment: I use the fact that $a_{m_k} $ converges to 0, which itself uses the fact that $a_n $ converges to 0.
Where it reads "should never be bigger than $z$ " it should be read "should never be smaller than $z$".

This is so because any number of the sequence that is smaller than $z$, by construction, is included in the sequence $a_n$.

Answer (score 3):

Your claim easily follows from the following lemma:

> **Lemma**: let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of positive numbers converging to zero such that $\sum_na_n=\infty$, and let $c$ be a positive real number. Then there exist some $n_1,n_2$ such that $$\frac c 2<\sum_{n=n_1}^{n_2}a_n<c$$

(To derive you claim, recursively plug in appropriate tails of the original sequence and the remaining part of $a$.)

To prove the lemma: let $n_1$ be such that for all $n\geq n_1$ we have $a_n<\frac c 2$, and let $n_2$ be the smallest integer such that $\sum_{n=n_1}^{n_2} a_n>\frac c 2$ (this exists because $\sum_{n=n_1}^\infty a_n=\infty$). Since $a_{n_2}<\frac c 2$ and $\sum_{n=n_1}^{n_2-1}a_n\leq \frac c 2$, we have $\sum_{n=n_1}^{n_2} a_n<\frac c 2+\frac c 2=c$. $\square$

Comment: What's with the $\square$ at the end?

Comment: @SimpleArt: That's a standard q.e.d. sign.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  It just looks a little silly.

Answer (score 2):

Claim: There are positive integers

$$m_1 \le n_1 < m_2 \le n_2  < m_3 \le n_3 < \cdots $$

such that if $S_k = \sum_{n=m_k}^{n_k}a_n,$ then

$$\tag 1 a-1/k < S_1 + \cdots + S_k <a$$

for all $k.$ Supposing the claim is true, set $A = \cup_k \{n: m_k \le n \le n_k\}.$ Then the desired subsequential series is $\sum_{n\in A} a_n.$

Proof of claim: Suppose $m_1,n_1, \dots , m_k,n_k$ have been chosen as above so that $(1)$ holds. Then there exists $m_{k+1}>n_k$ such that $n\ge m_{k+1}$ implies

$$a_n < \min(a-(S_1+ \cdots +S_k), 1/(k+1)).$$

Note that $S_1+ \cdots +S_k + a_{m_{k+1}} < a.$ Because $\sum_{m_{k+1}}^{\infty}a_n = \infty,$ there exists a smallest $N> m_{k+1}$ such that

$$S_1+\cdots + S_k +\sum_{m_{k+1}}^{N}a_n \ge a.$$

Define $n_{k+1} = N-1.$ Let's check that $(1)$ holds with $k+1$ in place of $k.$ That $S_1+\cdots + S_{k+1}<a$ is easy. For the lower bound we have

$$ S_1+\cdots + S_{k+1} + a_N \ge a \implies S_1+\cdots + S_{k+1} \ge a - a_N > a-1/(k+1).$$

This proves the claim except for a small point: I didn't deal with $S_1$ at the beginning. It should be clear how that would go.